# getGravity not working?

Tags: c++, game-physics, visual-c++-2010, bulletphysics

I am new to c++ as well as game development. I coded a function using bullet physics which returns the gravity of the world and it seems to be not working. It always returns 0. Though, I've initialized the world, solver, dispatcher, broadphase and collision configuration.

Here's the code:

```
void _setGravity(btScalar gravity) //sets the gravity of the world
{
    if(gravity > 0.f)
        gravity = -gravity;
    _dynamicsWorld->setGravity(btVector3(0, gravity, 0));
}

btScalar _getGravity(void) //returns the gravity of the world
{
return ((btScalar*)_dynamicsWorld->getGravity());
}
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: That casting looks very suspicious, why are you casting the result to a *pointer*?

Comment: I think the code of _dynamicsWorld setGravity and getGravity would help a lot. Also just a thought: You set the gravity as vector but return it as scalar....?

Comment: Instead of casting write a proper converter function. It will help you to understand where the problem is.

Comment: Don't use C-style casts. Use `static_cast`. If you need `reinterpret_cast` to make it compile, you probably have a bug.

Comment: I am never sure of this `(A*)a->x()`; which is 1st `->` or cast ?

Comment: Without casting it gave me this error: "'btVector3': actual parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`getGravity`](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtDynamicsWorld.html#a2a1de7e4e5456428d4558be6f24723ef) function returns a [`btVector3`](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtDynamicsWorld.html#a2a1de7e4e5456428d4558be6f24723ef) *by value*, so you need to use resulting vectors [`getY`](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtDynamicsWorld.html#a2a1de7e4e5456428d4558be6f24723ef) to get the gravity:

```
return _dynamicsWorld->getGravity().getY();
```

Comment: Thank you very very much, I might be needing more assistance. So, can you help me(future helps) ?

Comment: @rittik: If you have another question, just ask it here on stackoverflow.

Comment: @gartenriese Okay, so my next question is: How can I link my object to bullet physics ? Do I have to just render their positions ?

Comment: @rittik: I think that question is better asked at the [GameDev Exchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)